# Remove white spacing between cover image and sticky footer on large screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here is the link to the page I am developing http://ansh-test.bitballoon.com/ .
This website has been built with Bootstrap 3.

On the home page of this link I have a header, then a cover image with a filter overlay and finally a footer.  I have been able to make the footer function as a [sticky footer](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/). However on larger screens, there is an obnoxious white patch between the cover image and sticky footer when I increase the height of the browser.

1. I would like the cover image to overflow(dunno if thats the right terminology) using css to reach upto the point of the sticky footer so that there is no white patch seen in between.
2. I would also like to control and define the browser height at which the sticky footer should start showing up on the page.

Could someone help me figure this out for my link that i shared above?

Thanks!

Comment: It actually works as expected. Checked in Chrome and Firefox latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I set the `.bg-filter` div to have `min-height: 100vh;` instead and this sets it to always take up 100% of the screen height. You can fine-tune this value with media queries so that it takes into account the nav and footer heights and removes the need to scroll. Viewport units are pretty widely accepted so I wouldn't worry too much about browser support unless you need IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). For your second question, if I understand it correctly, you would need to use some js code set to the window scroll event to determine when it should appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content-wrap{ min-height:100%;}
@media (min-width: 1200px){

html , body{ height:100%;}
.bg-centerTop70 { height: 100vh; }

}
```

**The above aforementioned CSS will guide you to approch your result.**